# Filtrar por etiqueta a las preguntas sin respuestas. No funciona correctamente (en algunos casos)

Tags: discusión, bug, estado-por-diseño, etiquetas, barra-de-navegación

A veces suelo mirar las preguntas <kbd>Sin responder</kbd> → <kbd>no hay respuesta</kbd>.

[image: Sin responder >> no hay respuestas]

pero como casi que ya las conozco al día de hoy.

---

Quise usar el mismo filtro, pero que sólo mostrara las que tuvieran una etiqueta en concreto. Por ejemplo, `[android]`.

> Sé que se puede escribir directamente esta URL, pero no es cómoda:
>   https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android

Lo que intenté, mientras estaba en <kbd>Sin responder</kbd> → <kbd>no hay respuesta</kbd>, es escribir `[android]` en el buscador. Pero esto te envía a https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android

Creo que debería (no estoy seguro) quedarse en `/unanswered/`. No sé si esto es un bug o es el comportamiento deseado, aunque quizás yo este haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Creo que esa era la lógica que seguía el sitio de SO en inglés antes de que cambiaran la navegación y los filtros hace unas semanas/meses

Comment: @Mariano no es que le bug esta en los dos lados, yo publique aqui en meta en su dia  https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366/sistema-de-busqueda-filtrar-por-tag-no-funciona-correctamente-en-algunos-ca como usuario de SOes y en SOen como usuario de SOen. Saludos

Comment: @Mariano quizas te refieras a que parece que es solo para un caso de SOes porque el ejemplo esta con url de este sitio, puede ser pero es que practicamente hice un copy paste para notificarlo en el sitio original pero vamos que el bug estaba en los dos lados. Saludos

Comment: @Mariano yo hable con Juan M sobre esto una vez y le explique como replicar el error pues se intereso aunque quizas no lo entendio muy bien al leer este post es por eso que hablamos y le explique paso a paso, asi que me imagino que el lo comentaria con los responsables de este asunto, pero la verdad despues deje por un tiempo el sitio y nunca le pregunte que sucedio con eso tema.

Comment: @AngelAngel debo admitir que me costó un poco leerlo, pero creo que me ayuda que te respondí algo similar hace poco... Estoy intentando escribir una respuesta

Comment: @Mariano si ami tambien me daba esa sansacion cuando en su dia lo escribia pero es super simple basicamiente es que cuando haces una busqueda por tag estando en pregutas lo hace bien pero cuando estas en sin responder  y tu quieres ver una busqueda por tag esta la hace pero te redirecciona a .-> es. stackoverflow. com /questions /tagged / usando /questions  en lugar de /unanswered pues lo que tu quieres ver son las preguntas sin respuesta filtradas por tag, no filtrar todas las preguntas por tag.Saludos

Comment: @Mariano voy a publicarlo en stackexchange.Saludos

Comment: Si interpreté bien, es lo que respondí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> si estas en `Sin responder >> no hay respuesta` y aplicas el filtrar te envía a `Preguntas >> sin responder`, cuando lo que yo quería es que me las filtrara por las que no tienen respuesta.

Ese es el comportamiento esperado. Al escribir el nombre de una etiqueta en el campo de búsqueda, no toma la sección en la que estés (aunque sí recuerda la última pestaña utilizada). La idea, y el porqué de ese comportamiento, es que **no importa en dónde estés, los resultados de las búsquedas serán siempre los mismos**.

No importa si estás en "Sin responder", escribir `[android]` te mostrará los resultados de esa etiqueta (y no sólo las preguntas sin responder de Android).

Si quisieras ver todas las preguntas de Android con 0 respuestas, hay 2 alternativas:

1. Seleccionar `Sin responder >> no hay respuesta` y luego seleccionar la etiqueta en el módulo "**Etiquetas sin responder**" de la barra lateral.

   [image: Etiquetas sin responder]
2. Esribir en el campo de búsqueda `[android] answers:0` te devuelve sólo las preguntas con 0 respuestas.

   [image: android answers:0]
3. Guardar la URL `https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android` en maradores y usarla cuando quieras. Muchos de nosotros tenemos macadores para secciones de SOes que, de otra forma requieren escribir mucho o varios clicks. Al fin y al cabo, no pueden estar *todas* las opciones dentro de la página principal.

Comment: si ya eso lo deduci en su dia pero gracias por responder, pero aun asi que creo que no esta del todo bien pues si quieres filtrar los tag de la preguntas sin responder porque me redirecciona a preguntas, puedes usar esto directamente pero es mas incomodo -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/android asi que al tener esto se que la plataforma lo permite y o bien esta mal implementado o es ese el comportamiento que se queria, por otro lado con la nueva nav esto se disimula dependiendo de en que parte hagas la busqueda por tag me imagino que algun cambio han echo pero tampoco es que

Comment: yo pueda hacer nada para solucionarlo con lo que tampoco he puesto mucha atencion a los cambios en el nuevo nav y en que lugares hace la busqueda bien y en cuales se comporta en mi opinion de una manera extraña. Saludos

Comment: Escribir `[android]` en el cuadro de búsqueda no te mantiene dentro de "Sin responder", sino que efectúa una búsqueda de cero, sin importar en que sección te encuentres. Ese es el comportamiento deseado.

Comment: quizas lo sea, no lo dudo como dije en algun lugar, esto no tenia mucho sentido a mi forma de verlo (he hablado tanto de esto que no recuerdo donde lo dije), pero ahora con el nuevo nav al desaparecer el boton Sin responder pues si que tiene sentido pues haces la busqueda [android] y te vas a unanswered y las tienes filtradas, bajo mi punto de vista al no estar el boton sin responder es lo que hace que no genere esa duda de comportamiento extraño.

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, pero creo que lo más acertado es concluir que simplemente no funciona así.